# Tear in Vinyl Seat of 2003 Ford Ranger

Tags: ford, seat

I have a tear in the vinyl driver seat. I'm looking for a purely functional (read: not concerned with aesthetics) way to effectively patch the tear to prevent further tearing and degradation of foam padding.

I'm hoping for a better suggestion than duct tape. I'd rather avoid the inevitable sticky residue that is associated with duct tape.

[image: Vinyl Seat Tear]

Comment: Have you considered doing the "hillbilly" fix of using duct tape, and then buying seat covers to place over them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was doing some searching along these lines today and found something that you may be interested in. It is a transparent vinyl repair tape that has a very high rating on Amazon, and is relatively inexpensive. It's called **NRS Tear-Aid Patch**.

Another approach, though not perfect, is to:

1. Cut away the frayed edges
2. Get some dark brown upholster's thread
3. Get a curved sewing needle
4. Sew it together

If I was going to do it, what I would do is remove the seat. Then take off the cover, after learning how with Google searches. Then sew it together from the inside.  In fact I did a similar job on my grandson's Celica seat where it had pulled apart on a seam. The only thing is, looking at your picture, I think you might need two small matching pieces to fill the holes. You may be able to cut this from excess fabric under the seat.

Comment: I ordered a pack of Tear-Aid, just waiting for the weather to warm up for application. I'll post back with results.

Comment: I've had the Tear-Aid patch installed for just shy of a year. I've been very impressed. It has done a great job stopping the tear from getting worse. Some corners are peeling due to less than ideal placement of the patch, but there is no sticky residue. 

I anticipate it will hold up well for at least another 2 or 3 at which point (due to the age of the vehicle) I plan to just reapply.

Answer (score 2):

Most auto parts stores carry some sort of vinyl repair kit. They consist of a liquid that air dries. In your case you may want to tape the edges leaving some of the tear exposed while the repaired area dries, then move the tape and repeat the process until the entire tear is repaired. You could also make a patch and glue it to the seat with the repair compound. Another option might be to sew it closed and apply the vinyl repair compound over it to seal it.

Answer (score 0):

The area of your tear is in a place which will be stressed each every time you get on and off the seat. The apparent size of the tear is too great for plugging and patching, it will always be weak. This damage looks to be a seat cover replacement, either by yourself or an upholstery shop.